# How can I get the opacity animation to stop at the last frame of an animated SVG?

Tags: svg-animate

For some reason once the fade in of the object finishes it returns to being transparent again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<svg id="logo" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="926.529" height="926.53" viewBox="0 0 926.529 926.53"><title>12th and Midtown Logo</title>

<path id="circle" d="M915.953,463.265c0,250.013-202.676,452.689-452.688,452.689S10.576,713.278,10.576,463.265,213.252,10.576,463.265,10.576,915.953,213.252,915.953,463.265Z" fill="#d39d61" opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>



<rect id="frame" width="926.529" height="926.53" fill="none"/>

<animate id="changeopacity" xlink:href="#circle" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" begin="1s" dur="4s" repeatCount="1" restart="never" />
<animateTransform id="centercircle" xlink:href="#circle" attributeName="transform" begin="1s" type="translate" dur="3s" values="385,385;0,0"/>
<animateTransform id="resizecircle" xlink:href="#circle" attributeName="transform" begin="1s" additive="sum" type="scale" dur="3s" values=".05;1"/>


</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

By default SMIL animations are removed when they complete.  That's why your circle is going back to being transparent.  To fix, you just need to add:

```
fill="freeze"
```

to the "changeopacity" animation.

Here is corrected code:

```
<svg id="logo" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="926.529" height="926.53" viewBox="0 0 926.529 926.53"><title>12th and Midtown Logo</title>

<path id="circle" d="M915.953,463.265c0,250.013-202.676,452.689-452.688,452.689S10.576,713.278,10.576,463.265,213.252,10.576,463.265,10.576,915.953,213.252,915.953,463.265Z" fill="#d39d61" opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>

<rect id="frame" width="926.529" height="926.53" fill="none"/>

<animate id="changeopacity" xlink:href="#circle" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" begin="1s" dur="4s" repeatCount="1" restart="never" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="centercircle" xlink:href="#circle" attributeName="transform" begin="1s" type="translate" dur="3s" values="385,385;0,0"/>
<animateTransform id="resizecircle" xlink:href="#circle" attributeName="transform" begin="1s" additive="sum" type="scale" dur="3s" values=".05;1"/>
</svg>
```

The SMIL spec has a [section](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#Fill) that documents the fill attribute.